# How to modify this checkbox inside the GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have the following database design:

```
Employee Table: Username, Name, JobTitle, BadgeNo, IsActive, DivisionCode
Divisions Table: SapCode, DivisionShortcut
```

And I have a GridView that I am using it to add, delete and update/edit the employees information. This information is employee Username, Name, BadgeNo, JobTitle, IsActive and the DivisionShortcut. ***IsActive is a flag that indicates if the employee is available or in an assignment***. I made it as a checkbox and the column should show two values; Active and Inactive. In the Edit mode, the Checkbox will be displayed. If it is checked, then it means the employee is avaiable, otherwise it is inactive.

I wrote the code and everything works fine, but now I am facing two problems and I don't know how to make them work with my code.

1. The GridView shows True or False instead of Active and Inactive and
   I don't know why.
2. In the Edit mode, the checkbox will be displayed and the values (Active or Inactive) will be displayed besides to it and it shouldn't be displayed. I just want the checkbox to be displayed.

**So how to modify them?**

[image]

ASP.NET code:

```
<%-- GridView for User Management Subsystem --%>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Username" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="#DEBA84" 
             CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" BorderStyle="None" 
             BorderColor="#DEBA84">
            <FooterStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" 
              BackColor="#F7DFB5"></FooterStyle>
            <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" 
              HorizontalAlign="Center"></PagerStyle>
            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" 
              BackColor="#A55129"></HeaderStyle>
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ShowEditButton="true" ShowCancelButton="true"
                                EditImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" UpdateImageUrl="Images/icons/update24.png" 
                                CancelImageUrl="Images/icons/cancel324.png" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Division">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("DivisionShortcut")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DivisionsList" runat="server" DataSourceID="DivisionsListDataSource"
                                          DataTextField="DivisionShortcut" DataValueField="SapCode"
                                          SelectedValue='<%# Bind("DivisionCode")%>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Network ID" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="Username" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("Name")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job Title">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("JobTitle")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtJobTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("JobTitle")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Badge No.">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("BadgeNo")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBadgeNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BadgeNo")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active?">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("IsActive")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="isActive" runat="server" 
                                      AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="isActive_OnCheckedChanged"
                                      Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsActive")) %>'
                                      Text='<%# Eval("IsActive").ToString().Equals("True") ? " Active " : " Inactive " %>'/>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete?">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to Delete the record?')">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkB" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" CommandName="Delete" />
                        </span>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind:

```
//for updating the (IsActive) column using checkbox inside the GridView
    protected void isActive_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chkStatus = (CheckBox)sender;
        GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)chkStatus.NamingContainer;

        //Get the ID which is the NetworkID of the employee
        string username = gvrow.Cells[2].Text;
        bool status = chkStatus.Checked;

        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UsersInfoDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

        string updateIsActive = "UPDATE Employee SET IsActive = @IsActive WHERE Username = @Username";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateIsActive, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", status);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException se)
        {
            throw se;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

I update my code as following:
ASP.NET Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Username" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="#DEBA84" 
             CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" BorderStyle="None" 
             BorderColor="#DEBA84">
            <FooterStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" 
              BackColor="#F7DFB5"></FooterStyle>
            <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" 
              HorizontalAlign="Center"></PagerStyle>
            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" 
              BackColor="#A55129"></HeaderStyle>
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ShowEditButton="true" ShowCancelButton="true"
                                EditImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" UpdateImageUrl="Images/icons/update24.png" 
                                CancelImageUrl="Images/icons/cancel324.png" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Division">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("DivisionShortcut")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DivisionsList" runat="server" DataSourceID="DivisionsListDataSource"
                                          DataTextField="DivisionShortcut" DataValueField="SapCode"
                                          SelectedValue='<%# Bind("DivisionCode")%>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Network ID" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="Username" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("Name")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job Title">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("JobTitle")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtJobTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("JobTitle")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Badge No.">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("BadgeNo")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBadgeNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BadgeNo")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active?">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblIsActive" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IsActive")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="isActive" runat="server" 
                                      AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="isActive_OnCheckedChanged"
                                      Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsActive")) %>'
                                      Text='<%# Eval("IsActive")%>'/>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete?">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to Delete the record?')">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkB" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" CommandName="Delete" />
                        </span>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Code-Behind:

```
//For showing Active or Inactive in the IsActive column instead of True or False
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //Here we will select the IsActive column and modify its text
            Label isActive = new Label();
            isActive = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblIsActive");
            //Now, after getting the reference, we can set its text
            isActive.Text = "Active or Inactive";

            // First check Checkedbox is check or not, if not make it grey
            //if (e.Row.Cells[6].Text == "False")
            //    GridView1.BackColor = Color.Gray;

        }
    }
```

And I am getting the following error and I don't know why:
[image]

Comment: See my updated answer, I updated the GridView1_RowDataBound event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For question no: 1**
You have to add an Row_DataBound Event of your grid view, in which you select the IsActive  column and replaced its text by Active and InActive. But before going to code behind make a little change to you aspx code: In your item template instead of direct binding place a label control and bind it as I does in the below code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active?">
                <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:Label ID="lblIsActive" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IsActive") %>' ></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="isActive" runat="server" 
                                  AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="isActive_OnCheckedChanged"
                                  Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsActive")) %>'
                                  Text='<%# Eval("IsActive").ToString().Equals("True") ? " Active " : " Inactive " %>'/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)

{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // here you will select the IsActive column and modify it's text
        Label isActive=new Label();
        isActive = (Label) e.row.FindControl("lblIsActive");
        // after getting the reference set its text
        isActive.Text="Active or InActive";            

    }
}
```

For question no 2:
Remove the condition form this

```
Eval("IsActive").ToString().Equals("True") ? " Active " : " Inactive " %>'
```

and replace it with

```
 Eval("IsActive")
```

Now check boxes will be displayed.

**Updated Answer:**
`You are receiving an object reference not found error, Please debug your site and check it why you are unable to get the exact reference. I saw you code and it looks that your code is fine.`
To prove that my code is working,I created a gridview with a single column

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>                   
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>            
    </asp:GridView>
    // and bind this grid view in the Page_Load of my Page
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("name");

    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row[0] = "Waqar Janjua";
    dt.Rows.Add(row);

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    // When I view this page in the browser it shows "Waqar Janjua"
    // Now to update the columns text, I add the following code and it works.
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Row.RowState != DataControlRowState.Edit)
      {
      if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
        Label l = new Label();
        l = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label1");
        l.Text = "waqar";           
       }
      }
    }

   // When I run this page now, it shows me "Waqar" not "Waqar Janjua" The code works for me.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am getting this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
in the line `isActive.Text="Active or InActive";`

Comment: Besides that, it shows "Active or InActive" either the checkbox is checked or unchecked. Why?

Comment: @TechLover you are not getting the exact reference. Debug your site. and the label is bind to your database column so if in the database the value is true than it should show Active otherwise InActvie.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by getting the exact reference. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: @TechLover wait after checking it I will let you know.

Comment: thanks for your help. However, the problem doesn't happen during viewing the data. It only happens in the Edit mode. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: @TechLover what happen in the edit mode ? do you debug your site ? at which place the error occurs ?

Comment: @TechLover I guess it, add this codition `if (e.Row.RowState != DataControlRowState.Edit)` to your databound event. see my answer i updated it.

Comment: Thanks. It works very well now. I really appreciate your continuous help to me.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is returning "true" or "false" as it is expecting a boolean data type from IsActive. If you want to change that out put, I suspect you need to amend this conditionally on the ItemDataBound event of the grid.